# Are there compatibility issues opening Visual Studio Professional projects in Visual Studio Express, and vice versa?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

**Disclaimer**: I have taken a look at the 50+ StackExchange forums to find the right place, and it seems /Programmers/ is the most suitable Exchange for this. If this is the wrong place to ask this, however, please let me know - I will personally delete the thread.

I am in the process of downloading a single license for Visual Studio 2013 for my firm of 2-3 developers. One license is approximately $498.00 USD. As a small firm, our funds are short, but since we will be creating commercial software, we decided we will be needing the features of the Professional edition. At the same time, our decision is to use the Express edition for the rest of the two developers.

My question is - will there be compatibility issues between Express projects and Professional projects for Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe a MSDN subscription (e.g. the [Visual Studio Professional Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/buy.aspx)) can safe you some money as it decreases your overall license costs (with Windows Server and TFS).

Comment: We would like to decrease overall license costs in general - and the extra features I have noticed, I don't really have any need for them.

Comment: If you recently started your company, you can get Visual Studio Ultimate editions for free, among other things. Check out [Microsoft's BizSpark scheme](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) which gives free software to startups